# How to deep remove falsey values and empty objects from an object using lodash

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

How to deep remove all falsey values and empty objects using lodash ?

f.e. I want my object :

```
{ a:undefined, b:2, c:4, d:undefined , e:{ f:{} , g:null } }
```

to become:

```
{ b:2, c:4 };
```

Comment: What will happen for `e:{ f:'somevalue , g:null }`

Comment: e:{f:somevalue}

Comment: So it will recursively go through all objects? Also `{}` is not falsy.

Comment: Would a `for .. of` loop not work here? Then use an if and delete false properties?

Comment: What about empty arrays?

Comment: empty arrays could be removed as well @NinaScholz My attempt is not with lodash as I could not make them work on this. It is an optimization question .

Comment: please add your attempt. do you want to get a new object or only delete unwanted properties? do you have arrays as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var test = {
  a: undefined,
  b: 2,
  c: 4,
  d: undefined,
  e: {
    f: {},
    g: null
  }
};

function clean(obj) {
  for (var propName in obj) {
    if (_.isObject(obj[propName])) {
      clean(obj[propName]);
    }
    if (obj[propName] === null || obj[propName] === undefined || _.isObject(obj[propName]) && _.isEmpty(obj[propName])) {
      delete obj[propName];
    }
  }
}

clean(test);
console.log(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the properties to delete and get a clean object. This approach mutates to original object.

```js
function clean(value) {
    if (value === null || value === undefined) return true;
    if (typeof value !== 'object') return false;
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        let i = value.length;
        while (i--) if (clean(value[i])) value.splice(i, 1);
        return !value.length;
    }
    Object
        .keys(value)
        .filter(k => clean(value[k]))
        .forEach(Reflect.deleteProperty.bind(null, value));

    return !Object.keys(value).length;
}

const 
    object = { a: undefined, b: 2, c: 4, d: undefined, e: { f: {}, g: null } , h: [], i: [1, []], j: [[[], []]] };

clean(object);

console.log(object);
```

Comment: needless to ask why ... why?

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty vague and doesn't specify whether the original structure may or may not be mutated. There is also nothing in there about arrays.

This answer assumes that you don't want to mutate the original data structure and that "deep" also means to go through all array elements. If the object or array results in an empty instance the corresponding key will be removed.

```js
function deepCompact(collection) {
  const add = _.isArray(collection)
            ? (collection, key, value) => collection.push(value)
            : (collection, key, value) => collection[key] = value;
  
  return _.transform(collection, (collection, value, key) => {
    if (_.isObject(value)) {
      value = deepCompact(value);
      if (_.isEmpty(value)) return;
    } else {
      if (!value) return;
    }
    add(collection, key, value);
  });
}

const data1 = {a: undefined, b: 2, c: 4, d: undefined, e: {f: {} , g: null}};
console.log(deepCompact(data1));
const data2 = [{a: 0, b: 2}, false, {c: [{d: null}]}, {e: [{f: 1}]}];
console.log(deepCompact(data2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

[`transform`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#transform) is comparable to [`reduce`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#reduce), however the first callback parameter is locked to the provided or default accumulator. This means you don't have to return the accumulator from the callback. The default accumulator of `transform` also differs from `reduce`. `reduce` uses the first element as the initial value, whereas `transform` uses a new object with the same prototype as the provided collection as the default value.